# Why does this FO linear DE need an integrating factor?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

[This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1ybUTJ4BMI&list=PLj7p5OoL6vGwe4MSETi11Sa73CPD1JoCI&index=5) solves

$$(t+y+1)\textrm{d}t - \textrm{d}y = 0$$

using an integrating factor $\mu(t)=e^{-t}$ and obtains

$$y=-t-2+Ce^{-t}$$

The way I did it was more naive:

$$\int \textrm{d}y = \int (t + y + 1) \textrm{d}t$$

Why is my method incorrect?

Comment: What do you obtain after your last line ?

Comment: How do you integrate $y$ with respect to $t$ when $y$ is an unknown function of $t$?

Comment: By treating it as a constant, which I now realise was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is not incorrect, just that on the right you're back to square one, since you have the integral $\int y\mathrm dt$ to evaluate, whereas you need to know the relationship between $y$ and $t$ to do this, and that's what you wanted originally.